# XML instance prohibiting elements not defined in the schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am creating a XML schema for provide feedback to reporters of data.
How do I prevent another party creating an file based on the schema using  elements not defined in the schema?

Using the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="logical-model" 
           targetNamespace="logical-model"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="logicalModelErrors">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="reportSetAspects"/>
            <xs:element name="errorsPerEntity"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="reportSetAspects">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence >
            <xs:element name="aspect" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="aspect">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My instance is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logicalModelErrors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="logical-model" xsi:schemaLocation="logical-model LogMod.xsd">
  <reportSetAspects>
    <aspect name="bank identifier">BANK-ABDC1234</aspect>
    <aspect name="reporting reference date">2018-04-01</aspect>
    <abc>dd</abc>
  </reportSetAspects>
  <def>sss</def>
</logicalModelErrors>
```

If I validate this file in XMLSpy I get an error for `def` but not `abc`.
Error message:

> ```
> Element <def> is not allowed under element <logicalModelErrors>.
> Reason: No more elements expected.
> Error location: logicalModelErrors / def
> ```

Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Please edit your code and make it correct.  looks like you cut/pasted and are missing elements, as neither the xsd or xml are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
        <xs:element name="reportSetAspects"/>
```

to

```
        <xs:element ref="reportSetAspects"/>
```

in order to use your global declaration of `reportSetAspects`.  Otherwise, a new local declaration of `reportSetAspects` is used, and any content model is allowed in it because it specifies nothing more than the element name.

**Other notes:**

- `aspect` suffers a similar problem.
- `errorsPerEntity` currently allows any content for similar reasons.
- In your XSD, `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` [note missing `?`].

Comment: Thanks, clear now. copy paste error was the cause of the missing ?

Comment: Your comment also is missing something, probably `<markup/>`, which must be surrounded by backtick characters (`) in comments/questions or indented four spaces in questions in order to appear as itself.